# Debian 9 - Allow ONLY certain IP to MongoDB

Tags: debian, iptables, mongodb

How can I make my Mongo only certain IP accesible?

I've tried iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.111 -p tcp --destination-port 27016 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.2.111 -p tcp --source-port 27016 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
.
```

But, what **exactly** does that?
How can I *deny* all other IP?
How can I edit the iptables for adding more IP to allow and keeping blocking "not listed"?
How can I make this iptables configuration persitent?

I try my best english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, what exactly does that?

This is only two alone rules with no meaning.

> How can I deny all other IP?

There is two ways. **The first** is setting up deny policy with:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

But this way is no best practice because if you reset all rules you will lost connection to server. Use **the second** way:

You need "accept all" policy with the last rule in chains that deny all traffic:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

some rule...
some rule...
some rule...

iptables -A INPUT --destination $host --jump DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT --source $host --jump DROP
```

Where `$host` - is the host's ip address

> How can I edit the iptables for adding more IP to allow and keeping
>   blocking "not listed"?

You can add severall addresses or ip subnets to a single rule. For example:

```
iptables -A INPUT --source 192.168.2.111,192.168.2.1,192.168.56.0/24 --destination $host --protocol tcp --dport 27016 --jump ACCEPT
```

> How can I make this iptables configuration persitent?

With `iptables-persistent`

---

**Pay attention**: if you deny or drop all INPUT/OUTPUT traffic you need to define accepting rules for proper connection to server.

For `ssh`:

```
iptables -A INPUT --source 192.168.2.111 --protocol tcp --dport 22 --jump ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --match conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
```

Use iptables carefully especially on remote servers which you cannot access directly if something went wrong.

Comment: Thank you, but when I run `iptables -P INPUT DROP` or `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` the terminal hang. :(

Comment: And then `packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.2.180 port 22: Broken pipe`

Comment: Yes, it is normal. See **Pay attention** section above. Do not add rules line by line in terminal, do it in script

Comment: iptables uses rules by order. Place allowing rules at the top and denying rules at the bottom.

Comment: :( Sorry, I'm ultra very new at iptables.

Comment: So, with *nano* I create the script, and now how I run it?

Comment: Script have to be .sh?

Comment: yes. with X-permission

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/d6YAFb/Captura_de_pantalla_2017_10_05_a_la_s_3_17_12_p_m.png

Comment: I wrote a .sh file, added -x permission, and then run.

Comment: `packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.2.180 port 22: Broken pipe` again

Comment: but https://image.ibb.co/cbuHvb/Virtual_Box_S_05_10_2017_15_21_56.png

Comment: I checked iptables list, and now seems like everything is "ok"

Comment: How to use iptables-persistent?

Comment: see http://www.microhowto.info/howto/make_the_configuration_of_iptables_persistent_on_debian.html